# Изменение прозрачности текста, в зависимости от введённого запроса

Tags: javascript, html5

Есть поле для ввода, кнопка "Ввод" и таблица с двумя ячейками, в каждой из которых есть по одному ответу: "Ответ1" и "Ответ2". Изначально opacity текстов в обоих ячейках равны 0. Мне нужно, чтобы при введении в поле ввода текста: "ответ1", в первой ячейке был opacity: 1, аналогично со вторым ответом. При этом, если пользователь трижды ввёл неправильный ответ, opacity обеих ячеек будет равно 1.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Вопрос-ответ</title>
<style>
  .otvet1 {
   opacity: 0; 
  }
  .otvet2 {
   opacity: 0;
  }
</style>
```

```
<p>
  <b>Ваш ответ:</b><br>
  <input type="text" size="40">
  <button>Ввод</button>
    <table class="tab" border="1">
 <tr>
  <th class="otvet1">Ответ1</th>
  <th class="otvet2">Ответ2</th>
 </tr>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заменил opacity на visibility, т.к. в opacity нет необходимости.
Не вставляйте таблицу в тег *р*. Стили лучше добавить в CSS а не в HTML.

```js
var ctInput = $('input');
var answers = $('td');

$('button').click(function(e) {
  this.wrongAnswers = this.wrongAnswers || 0;
  var text = ctInput.val();

  var hasMatch = false;
  $.each(answers, function(index, ct) {
    if ($(ct).text() === text) {
      $(ct).removeClass('transparent');
      ct.isValidAnswerGiven = true;
      hasMatch = true;
    } else if (!ct.isValidAnswerGiven && !$(ct).hasClass('transparent')) {
      $(ct).addClass('transparent');
    }
  });

  if (!hasMatch) {
    this.wrongAnswers++;
  }

  if (this.wrongAnswers > 2) {
    $.each(answers, function(index, ct) {
      if (!ct.isValidAnswerGiven) {
        $(ct).removeClass('transparent');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.transparent {
  visibility: hidden;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td,
th {
  padding: 3px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>Ваш ответ:</b>
<br>
<input type="text" />
<button>Ввод</button>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="transparent">Ответ1</td>
    <td class="transparent">Ответ2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Всё хорошо, но, если набрать один ответ, а затем второй, то будет показан последний, а первый исчезнет и, если набрать неверный ответ, после правильного, исчезнет тот, что был (нужно, чтобы если было введено 2 правильных ответа или неправильный после правильного, ни один из них не исчезал)

Comment: Подкорректировал. Хотя в этом случае лучше проявить самостоятельность, поскольку это уже частный случай.

Comment: Да, всё отлично работает. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы не имело значения с заглавной буквы набирать или нет?

Comment: Вместо if ($(ct).text() === text) написать if ($(ct).text().toLowerCase() === text.toLowerCase())
Хороший учебник по [javascript](http://learn.javascript.ru/)

Comment: Да, всё отлично работает! Спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: Прошу прощение за беспокойство, но по каким-то непонятным причинам на сайте код работает отлично, но при копировании кода в редактор и последующим его открытии ничего не работает. Не могли бы вы скинуть мне на почту исходные файлы вашего кода: an-vol.volckov@yandex.ru? Заранее большое спасибо!